# gudhi python module installed but won't import

Tags: python-import

After importing the gudhi module like:

```
$ conda config --add channels conda-forge
$ conda install -c vincentrouvreau gudhi

import gudhi
```

gives import error. python2.7 is installed. Path variable lists the python path. What others have to be checked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

gudhi packages are only available for Python 3.6 for the moment.
I am working for them to be available on conda-forge, but I still have some compilation issue.

You can install GUDHI Python version by doing :

Install Miniconda (for instance) Python 3.6 x64 from here : https://conda.io/miniconda.html

In a command line :

```
conda config --add channels conda-forge
conda install -c vincentrouvreau gudhi
python
>>> import gudhi
```

Then you can try examples from documentation : http://gudhi.gforge.inria.fr/python/latest/

Regards,

Vincent Rouvreau

Comment: Hi Vincent - really like the look of your gudhi library. Any chance there will be Python 2.7 support coming any time soon?

Comment: Hello, the [GUDHI conda package](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/gudhi) is now available thanks to conda-forge. It is not possible for Windows because we are using c++11 that requires msvc 14 as explained [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers)